# c# Resort a list

Tags: c#, sorting

This is a pretty complicated sort. Basically I take a list of **Answers** and I order them by **Question** priority first. Priority is a zero based integer (0 being the highest priority).
What I want to do then, is sort each answer by it's priority.
For example, like this:

```
var answers = new List<AnswerRequestModel>
{
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        Priority = 0,
        Text = "Very high"
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 2,
        Priority = 1,
        Text = "High"
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 3,
        Priority = 2,
        Text = "Medium"
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 4,
        Priority = 3,
        Text = "Low"
    }
};
```

This assumes there is only one question. If there were two questions:

```
var answers = new List<AnswerRequestModel>
{
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 1,
        Priority = 0,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
        Text = "Very high",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Very high", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 2,
        Priority = 1,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
        Text = "High",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "High", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 3,
        Priority = 2,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
        Text = "Medium",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Medium", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 4,
        Priority = 3,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
        Text = "Low",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Low", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 5,
        Priority = 0,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1},
        Text = "Blacks",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Blacks", Operator = "=", Field = "colour"} }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 6,
        Priority = 1,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
        Text = "Silvers",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Silvers", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 7,
        Priority = 2,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
        Text = "Reds",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Blues", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
    },
    new AnswerRequestModel
    {
        Id = 8,
        Priority = 3,
        Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
        Text = "Yellows",
        Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Yellows", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
    }
};
```

In both these examples, the order is correct. But now comes the complication.
If I select an answer. I need it to resort, also if the answers and questions come in the wrong order I want them to be sorted correctly.
The method needs to also work when selecting multiple answers.

My method currently looks like this:

```
public IList<AnswerRequestModel> SortAnswersByPriority(IList<AnswerRequestModel> answers)
{
    if (!answers.Any()) return answers;

    var chosenAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Active).ToList();
    var sortedAnswers = answers.OrderBy(m => m.Question.Priority).ThenBy(m => m.Priority);

    if (!chosenAnswers.Any())
        return sortedAnswers.ToList();

    var questionIds = answers.GroupBy(m => m.Question.Id).Select(m => m.Key).ToList();
    foreach(var questionId in questionIds)
    {
        var questionAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Question.Id == questionId).ToList();
        if (!questionAnswers.Any()) continue;

        var highestPriority = questionAnswers.OrderBy(m => m.Priority).First().Priority;
        var chosenQuestionAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Active).ToList();
        var count = chosenQuestionAnswers.Count;

        var ordered = questionAnswers.OrderBy(a => 1);
        switch (count)
        {
            case 1:
                var choseHighest = chosenQuestionAnswers.SingleOrDefault(m => m.Priority.Equals(highestPriority)) != null;
                ordered = choseHighest ? ordered.OrderBy(m => m.Priority) : ordered.OrderByDescending(m => m.Priority);
                break;
            default:
                ordered = ordered.ThenByDescending(m => m.Active).ThenByDescending(m => m.Priority);
                break;
        }

        var questionAnswerIds = ordered.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
        sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers.ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id));
    }

    return sortedAnswers.ToList();
}
```

If I put a breakpoint on `sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers.ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id));` I can see that my sort is working correctly, because the answer ids are sorted. But when it executes the line with the breakpoint, nothing changes.

Can someone help me figure this out?

Comment: If you change `sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers.ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id));` to `sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers.ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id)).ToList();` does it work?

Comment: It would be awesome if you could bring your code samples into a single [mcve] so we are able to debug and run it at our end.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this, but I think it was actually an issue with my logic rather than anything else. I changed my method to this:

```
public IList<AnswerRequestModel> SortAnswersByPriority(IList<AnswerRequestModel> answers)
{
    if (!answers.Any()) return answers;

    var chosenAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Active).ToList();

    // If we have no chosen answers, then just do a default sort by priority
    if (!chosenAnswers.Any()) return answers.OrderBy(m => m.Question.Priority).ThenBy(m => m.Priority).ToList();

    var sortedAnswers = answers.OrderBy(a => 1);
    var questionIds = answers.GroupBy(m => m.Question.Id).Select(m => m.Key).ToList();
    foreach(var questionId in questionIds)
    {
        var questionAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Question.Id == questionId).ToList();
        if (!questionAnswers.Any()) continue;

        var lowestPriority = questionAnswers.OrderByDescending(m => m.Priority).First().Priority;
        var chosenQuestionAnswers = answers.Where(m => m.Active).ToList();
        var count = chosenQuestionAnswers.Count;
        var ordered = questionAnswers.OrderBy(a => 1);

        // Sort by our chosen answers first, then by answer priority
        if (chosenQuestionAnswers.Any(m => m.Priority.Equals(lowestPriority)))
        {
            switch (count)
            {
                case 1:
                    ordered = ordered.OrderByDescending(m => m.Priority);
                    break;
                default:
                    ordered = ordered.OrderByDescending(m => m.Active).ThenByDescending(m => m.Priority);
                    break;
            }
        } else
        {
            ordered = ordered.OrderByDescending(m => m.Active).ThenBy(m => m.Priority);
        }

        var questionAnswerIds = ordered.Select(m => m.Id).ToList();
        sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers.ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id));
    }

    // Once we have sorted by our answer priority, do a final sort on question priority and return the list
    return sortedAnswers.OrderBy(m => m.Question.Priority).ToList();
}
```

and in answer to @mjwills, the code I supplied should have been enough for you to run locally. If you created a model **AnswerRequestModel** and a the `SortAnswersByPriority` method and passed in the list I used in my example, you should be able to execute it without issue.

I could have supplied my unit test:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldSortOnMultipleQuestionsWithOneChosenAnswerPerQuestion()
{
    // Assemble
    var services = SortContext.GivenServices();
    var sortProvider = services.WhenCreateSortProvider();
    var answers = new List<AnswerRequestModel>
    {
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 1,
            Priority = 0,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
            Text = "Very high",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Very high", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 2,
            Priority = 1,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
            Text = "High",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "High", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 3,
            Priority = 2,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
            Text = "Medium",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Medium", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 4,
            Priority = 3,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two },
            Text = "Low",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Low", Operator = "=", Field = "quality"} }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 5,
            Priority = 0,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1},
            Text = "Blacks",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Blacks", Operator = "=", Field = "colour"} }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 6,
            Priority = 1,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
            Text = "Silvers",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Silvers", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 7,
            Priority = 2,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
            Text = "Reds",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Blues", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
        },
        new AnswerRequestModel
        {
            Id = 8,
            Priority = 3,
            Question = new QuestionRequestModel { Type = QuestionType.Two, Priority = 1 },
            Text = "Yellows",
            Formulas = new List<AnswerFormula> { new AnswerFormula { Expression = "Yellows", Operator = "=", Field = "colour" } }
        }
    };
    answers[1].Active = true;
    answers[6].Active = true;

    // Act
    var sortedAnswers = sortProvider.SortAnswersByPriority(answers);
    var firstAnswer = sortedAnswers[0];
    var secondAnswer = sortedAnswers[1];
    var thirdAnswer = sortedAnswers[2];
    var forthAnswer = sortedAnswers[3];
    var fifthAnswer = sortedAnswers[4];
    var sixthAnswer = sortedAnswers[5];
    var seventhAnswer = sortedAnswers[6];
    var eigthAnswer = sortedAnswers[7];

    // Assert
    firstAnswer.Text.Should().Be("High");
    secondAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Very high");
    thirdAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Medium");
    forthAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Low");
    fifthAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Reds");
    sixthAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Blacks");
    seventhAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Silvers");
    eigthAnswer.Text.Should().Be("Yellows");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Unless your breakpoint is after the ToList() then you won't see a change. The OrderBy/ThenBy methods are implemented using deferred execution. Until you start enumerating the ThenBy query (i.e. using a foreach or ToList/ToArray) you won't see any changes.

```
sortedAnswers = sortedAnswers
    .ThenBy(m => questionAnswerIds.IndexOf(m.Id))
    .ToList(); // put your break point after this line
```